# Push Notification on Apple Wallet Card APNS

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, push

I am trying to send push notification on ios wallet app , on my created card, i use the library to generate my card "pkpass/pkpass": "^1.2.0", i tried the

i also tried the socket based but get message of success , but i didnt recieve the notification.

code as bellow :

```
$device_token   = '<device_token>';
$pem_file       = '/var/www/html/certificate.pem';
$pem_secret     = '123';
$apns_topic     = 'pass.com.loyaltycards';

$sample_alert = '{"aps":{}}';
$url = "https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

var_dump($response);
var_dump($httpcode);
```

i am getting error of "{ reason: 'BadDeviceToken' }"

getting token like as follow when i install my card :

/index_event.php/v1/devices/7181c8d842a0c71f92bbdd7055b47dc5/registrations/pass.com.artedigital/c_70_37

Comment: Please edit your post to explain exactly what it was that you first tried. You seem to have left that out.

Comment: @DanielHolmes Please check now , i am getting error of { reason: 'BadDeviceToken' }